# How to print the value of a memory address that has been cast to type 'unsigned char*'?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-address

I am working on some simulation software, in which I have two programs communicating with each other. One has been written in c++, and the other in Ada.

I am currently working on a part of the c++ program, in which a message is being sent to the stack, where it will be read by the Ada program. This message contains a pointer to a location in memory where a variable of type `dataPipeBMessage` is held... however, the data at that memory location is being cast to an `unsigned char *` to be sent.

Because the `dataPipeBMessage` variable contains a struct, one of whose elements is a `union`, I want to see which elements of the `union` are being sent in the message, so I have added a `printf` statement just below where the message is sent, to try and display the contents of the message in the console...

However, I am unsure how to print the value of a pointer variable that has been cast to an `unsigned char *`... The code I have is as follows:

```
TheStackInterface->writeToStackNonBlocking(
        ... ,
        (unsigned char*)&dataPipeBMessage,
        ...);
    printf("\n Value of message being sent: %s", &dataPipeBMessage);
```

When I run the program, the output that this `printf` statement gives me in the console is just a single unreadable character (little circle with an arrow on the top). Can anyone explain to me how I would display the value of this variable/ memory address in the console output?

Comment: Are you trying to print the value of the pointer, or the value of the pointee?

Comment: Wait, do you need the pointer adress, or the string value printed?

Comment: I'm trying to display the inormation that is held at the pointer address- i.e. the actual data that is being sent in the message.

Comment: You're trying to print a structure as if it were a zero-terminated string (`%s`). You'll need to print it member by member, or create something printable from it.

Comment: On closer reading, you seem to believe that the cast to `unsigned char*` of the function parameter modifies the data it points to ("the data at that memory location is being cast..."). It doesn't.

Comment: I didn't think that it modified the actual data pointed to- I thought (possibly incorrectly?) that it would be possible to read the data as a pointer to an `unsigned char`, even though it was set as a `dataPipeBMessage`... Is this possible? i.e. because I'm looking at the actual data in the memory, rather than at the variable, can I read it as a different type to what it is?

Comment: As mentioned in my OP, the element of the `struct` whose data at its memory location that I am trying to read is a `union`- which is how it is possible that this part of the memory could contain any one of several different data types.

Comment: Well, you can print out the individual bytes, if that's what you want, but not as a null-terminated string.

Comment: Will that allow me to see what information the bytes hold in a human- readable (as opposed to machine- readable) way? If so, how would I do that?